# Android 9 frozen ui after unlocking screen

Tags: android, kotlin

I am building timer application, I have a viewmodel that processes timer data (implemented with rxjava) and holds it in livedata object, then there is fragment that subscribes to this livedata and shows it in view.

So the flow is that timer is running somewhere in viewmodel and current time left is exposed to view through livedata. I am testing that timer is still running even if I rotate screen, lock the screen and return and so on.

On Android 9 if I lock the screen and then come back to it, the ui is frozen - updates from timer livedata is not shown in views. I am logging that fragment is indeed receiving these timer updates but it is not shown in the views for some reason. I was able to reproduce it only on Android 9.

fragment code:

```
class TomatoFragment : BaseFragment<FragmentTomatoBinding, TomatoFragmentViewModel>(), OnBackPressedCallback {

companion object {
    fun newInstance() = TomatoFragment()
}

override val viewModelClass = TomatoFragmentViewModel::class.java
override val layoutId = R.layout.fragment_tomato

////// some stuff

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    viewModel.initTomato()

    initObservers()
}

private fun initObservers() {
    observe(viewModel.getViewData()) {
        val newText = it.getMainActionText(extendedFabTomatoSession.context)
        extendedFabTomatoSession.text = newText

        Log.d("SRA4KA", "time left: ${it.getShownTimeFormatted(requireContext())}")
        textTomatoTimeLeft.text = it.getShownTimeFormatted(requireContext())
    }

 // some other stuff   
}
```

It seems really bizarre, because I literally log that the text is being set but nothing changes on the screen. I recorded a video of it : https://youtu.be/l9kUexJKyaY

**UPDATE**
I searched google issue tracker and found https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/118178434 which could be same/similar issue

Answer (score 1):

I experienced this before. You need to quickly display and hide an alert dialog in the onResume of ur Fragment or Activity. This action will prevent the screen from freezing.

Answer (score 0):

As Jeff Emuveyan mentioned, this code snippet in onResume() did the trick for me:

```
    AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
    alertDialog.show();
    alertDialog.dismiss();
```